# Outlook's API hanging before granting request?

Tags: api, outlook-restapi

Is the [Node.js tutorial](https://github.com/jasonjoh/node-tutorial) for Outlook's Mail API out of date?

I cloned the repo, installed the versions the dependencies from there:

```
"@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client": "^0.4.0",
"es6-promise": "^4.1.0",
"simple-oauth2": "^1.0.1"
```

And registered the app, added a valid redirect URI and a replaced the Secret Key and Client ID, but for some reason, I'm getting an `Access token error:  Bad Request` error. Error is coming from this endpoint:

`http://localhost:8000/authorize?code=M05e30bdf-af17-916a-8707-b1a8eafdc6b2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should update those dependencies to:

```
"@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client": "^1.0.0",
"es6-promise": "^4.1.0",
"simple-oauth2": "^1.4.0"
```

There is an issue with the sample if you login with an Outlook.com address as it looks like you're doing. The problem is that there is no `mail` attribute on the Outlook.com user as returned by Graph.

The quick fix is to replace the line of code in the `getUserEmail` function from:

```
callback(null, res.mail);
```

to:

```
callback(null, res.mail ? res.mail : res.userPrincipalName);
```

All that being said you probably should have logged this as an issue in the GitHub repository :)